# C memory stack and heap

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
  int a = 5, *ptr;
  ptr = &a;

  printf("0x%X\n", ptr);
  printf("%p\n", &ptr); //Why are these the same? 
  printf("%d\n", *ptr);

  ptr++;

  printf("0x%X\n", ptr);
  printf("%p\n", &ptr); //Why are these the same? 
  printf("%d\n", *ptr);

  return 0; 
}
```

Why are those two values the same? Since I incremented the pointer shouldn't the address change as well?

Comment: Try `printf("%p\n", ptr);` instead of `printf("0x%X\n", ptr);`.

Answer (score 4):

you incremented `ptr`'s value. It still resides in the same place in memory. `&ptr` tells you its address.  This is no different than doing something like `a++`.  If you print out `a`'s value, it will now be 6, but if you print out the address of `a` with `printf("%p\n", (void*)&a);`, it will be the same before and after the increment.

Comment: How do I increment the actual address of ptr? I'm trying to cause a seg fault by increasing the pointer until I run out of memory.

Comment: You cannot increment the address of a variable @TrevorGood.  It is the variable's most fundamental characteristic -- more so even than its name.  Its address is its *identity*.

Comment: @TrevorGood: If you want to create a seg fault, set the value of `ptr` to `NULL` (or some well-known bad address) and then try to dereference it.

Comment: I'm suppose to iterate over all the addresses in the stack, and cause a segfault, by having my pointer point to a location that is not allocated within the stack. I'm so confused as to how to do this. When start incrementing the pointer it just goes on forever never reaching a segfault.

Comment: @TrevorGood accessing memory you don't own may cause a segfault. In the code shown, you're incrementing once, not forever. Put `ptr++` in a long-running loop. Secondly, _access_ is the key. Try to read/write to that location each time. Eventually you'll reach memory you don't own, and your OS will most likely raise a segfault to terminate your program. Try wrapping from `ptr++` to just before `return 0;` in a `while(1)` loop and see what happens.

Comment: I have a loop thats a million, and all the program does is run not cause a segfault? Could you just give me a quick example, I'm so lost.

Comment: @TrevorGood Post the code you're actually running with in the question,, nobody here is looking over your shoulder and can see what you're doing. But "How can I force a segfault?" is an entirely different question from "Why doesn't this variable's address change?". If something like `while(1){ ptr++; *ptr = 3;}` doesn't do it then ask a new question and copy and paste your code into it.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a = 5, *ptr;
  ptr = &a;
 
  while(1){ 
    ptr++; 
    *ptr = 3;
    printf("%p\n", &ptr); 
  }
  return 0;
} And the address isnt changing.

Comment: @TrevorGood segfaults for me no problem after ~200 iterations I'd guess. Are you sure you're even compiling it? This is getting way beyond the scope of the question, and back and forth in comments isn't how SO works. If you're still having problems creating a segfault with that code ask a new question.

Comment: @TrevorGood The address *can't* change. Like JohnBollinger said, that's the intrinsic identifying property that makes that variable unique. A different address means a different place in memory which means a different variable (or whatever is there). Trying to make that variable exist at a different location is like trying to make 2 objects occupy the same location in spacetime.

Comment: Cant ask another question for 90min :(\

Comment: @TrevorGood Are you even running with an operating system? If you're running this on some bare metal chip I'm not sure what will happen, but you probably won't get a segfault. Are you 100% sure you're compiling that code and running the resulting executable? I've been burned before running old/stale executables that didn't match up with my code changes for a variety of reasons. You should change that to `printf("%p\n", (void*)&ptr);`, but I highly doubt that would be preventing a segfault.

Comment: Yep im just running ubuntu. https://pastebin.com/Tr77iBnv. And I'm now getting a segfault, thanks. But the print statement isn't changing the address of the pointer? And thanks for the help, its greatly appreciated.

Comment: @TrevorGood Finally! glad to hear it. Printing the address of `ptr` is never going to change. That's like me continually asking who you are and each time you give me a name different than TrevorGood. You are TrevorGood, that's never going to change. The _value_ of `ptr` changes, not `ptr` itself. It's the same thing with `a`. You can change the _value_ of `a` all you want, but its location in memory remains fixed. A pointer is nothing more than a variable whose _value_ is an address.

Comment: Your code should increment a pointer that points at the
heap, by 1 byte, repeatedly, until the program crashes. That's the question, that I have to answer. So, from the question I'm essentially using up every address in the heap, by assigning something to it, and then incrementing the pointer to a different address, assigning something to it, and so on?

Comment: @TrevorGood well,, no. You're on the stack and you're incrementing `ptr` by `sizeof(int)` each time (probably 4 bytes, but it depends on your system). If you want something from the heap you need to [`malloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) it first, and use `char` instead of `int` to get 1 byte. Read in your book about the stack and the heap, do some googling. If you're still lost in (now 60 min?) ask another question. This discussion has gone way beyond the scope of your original question. SO comment section isn't the place to learn these things.

Answer (score 3):

1. 5 is the value of `a` and `&a` is the address of `a`.
2. `ptr = &a` means address of `a` equals the value of `ptr`.
3. `&ptr` is the address of `ptr`.

You can think of `ptr` as a box that can hold an address as it's value.

When you increment `ptr` you change the address held inside the box i.e. `ptr`; not the address of the box itself.